# How to design RF Matching circuit for Transmitter MCU (BC66F2245)?

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance-matching, transmitter

I am designing a PCB where i use the Holtek BC66F2245 Transmitter MCU to send data using RF at 433MHz. I'm currently drawing the schematic in Altium and now i've come to the point of designing the matching circuit.

I am sending my data at 433MHz with a 50Ohm antenna, that is all i know. I've watched many videos about matching circuits so I know exactly what it's used for and why it's needed, but I have no idea how to design one for my MCU since the data sheet provides me with no more information than the image below.
[image: Application circuit in Datasheet]
How do I start with designing a matching circuit for this MCU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How do I start with designing a matching circuit for this MCU?*

Start by breaking things down and giving them names: -

[image]

- Z1 (in green) matches the complex output impedance of the RFout port to a resistive value at your operating frequency. Basically it can be as simple as a series tuned LC that is terminated in the naturally resistive impedance of the Pi filter.
- Z2 (in blue) matches the complex impedance of an antenna to a resistive value (usually 50 Ω) at your operating frequency. If your antenna is 50 Ω then no need for the inductor.
- Pi network (in red) matches the resistive impedance coming from Z1 to the resistive impedance presented by the antenna and Z2 at your operating frequency

The one to concentrate on is usually the Pi filter. Here's an extract from [my website](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20PI%20LP.html) on how to design one: -

[image]

So, plug the numbers into the on-line calculator I linked and see what you come up with. There is more information on the link BTW.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I have a better understanding of what i have to design now. Though i still don't understand how I can determine the "complex output impedance of the RFout port". I feel like this value should be given in the datasheet but I can't seem to find it. Or is there a different way to determine this value?

Here is a link to the datasheet: https://www.holtek.com/documents/10179/116711/BC66F2235_45_55v110.pdf

Comment: @MirteHolm if the data sheet you linked doesn't contain that information (it appears to have the word "impedance" mentioned only once in it) then you should contact the supplier to get this information. Most chips that operate in UHF normally provide this information as a table of values vs operating frequency.

Comment: It's been a while but I've contacted the suppliers and after a lot of back and forth they gave me the following complex output impedance: 53.4-219.2J. I have tried using your calculator but I can't figure out what to put as Rx, since my complex impedance is -219.2J?